# Parse dynamic JSON

Tags: c#, json.net

I am using c# and json.net 9.0.1

I have the following json

```
    {
        "lineups": [
          {
            "55": {
              "id": "55",
              "game_id": "1",
              "player_id": "55",
              "jersey_number": "78"
            },
            "56": {
              "id": "56",
              "game_id": "1",
              "player_id": "56",
              "jersey_number": "77"
            },
            "57": {
              "id": "57",
              "game_id": "1",
              "player_id": "57",
              "jersey_number": "76"
            }
        }
     ]
 }
```

All of the array items are of type Player.  How can I parse the json so that each item "55", "56", "57" are stored in a list of Players, List?

The source json can't be modified as it is coming from a 3rd party.

**UPDATE**
Modified the json to be valid,

Comment: deserialize it to a `Dictionary<string,Player>` where your keys `55`, `56`, etc will become the keys in the dictionary.

Comment: The JSON in your example isn't valid JSON... (opening `{` inside the lineups array, but no corresponding closing) Do you really need to parse malformed JSON, or is the example bad? Please _edit_ the question to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you created two classes like this:

```
public class Lineup
{
    public List<Dictionary<string,Player>> lineups;
}

public class Player
{
    public string id {get; set; }
    public string game_id { get; set;}
    public string player_id {get;set;}
    public string jersey_number {get;set;}
}
```

Then you should (after you've fixed your invalid JSON), be able to deserialize like this:

```
var l = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Lineup>(source);
```

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/e7eUUZ

You can also use the various attributes in JSON.Net to customize the deserialization. For example, you might want to use the `JsonPropertyAttribute` to map the names in your JSON source to C# property names that match the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Given these classes:

```
public class Lineup
{
    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{
    public string id { get; set; }

    public string game_id { get; set; }

    public string player_id { get; set; }

    public string jersey_number { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public List<Lineup> Lineups { get; set; }
}
```

You could implement a custom JsonConverter like this:

```
public class LineupConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Lineup);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;

        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartObject)
            throw new Exception("Expected an object");

        var jObject = (JObject)JObject.ReadFrom(reader);

        // I suspect the property name are the same as the id property
        // of the contained objects. Discarding the information from serialization
        var players = jObject.Properties()
            .Select(p => p.Value.ToObject<Player>());

        return new Lineup
        {
            Players = players.ToList()
        };

    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And then use:

```
var lineups = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(json, new LineupConverter());
```

You could also annotate the `Player` properties with `JsonProperty` attributes and have them more C#-like.

Comment: Custom parser is an overkill. See @Matt Burland's answer.

Comment: @Shiva I agree a parser is an overkill in this case. I believe giving an alternative will at least make Fetbi aware of his options should he encounter another case that might warrant the use of a custom Converter.